# Installing GDB broke LLDB, how do I fix LLDB?

Tags: lldb

On Ubuntu 18.04.1, I have been using `lldb` and `llnode` to debug `node`. I was curious to see if `gdb` would be any better, so I installed it. After that, `lldb` failed to load `core` files anymore.

This worked:

```
~$ lldb /usr/bin/node -c core
(lldb) target create "/usr/bin/node" --core "/home/ubuntu/core"
Core file '/home/ubuntu/core' (x86_64) was loaded.'
```

Then I installed `gdb`:

```
~$ sudo apt install gdb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gdbserver libbabeltrace1 libc6-dbg libdw1
Suggested packages:
  gdb-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gdb gdbserver libbabeltrace1 libc6-dbg libdw1
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 8737 kB of archives.
After this operation, 51.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libdw1 amd64 0.170-0.4 [203 kB]
Get:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libbabeltrace1 amd64 1.5.5-1 [154 kB]
Get:3 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 gdb amd64 8.1-0ubuntu3 [2937 kB]
Get:4 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 gdbserver amd64 8.1-0ubuntu3 [282 kB]
Get:5 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libc6-dbg amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1 [5161 kB]
Fetched 8737 kB in 1s (10.8 MB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package libdw1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 125740 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdw1_0.170-0.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdw1:amd64 (0.170-0.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbabeltrace1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libbabeltrace1_1.5.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbabeltrace1:amd64 (1.5.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gdb.
Preparing to unpack .../gdb_8.1-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gdb (8.1-0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gdbserver.
Preparing to unpack .../gdbserver_8.1-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gdbserver (8.1-0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc6-dbg:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dbg_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libdw1:amd64 (0.170-0.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up gdbserver (8.1-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libbabeltrace1:amd64 (1.5.5-1) ...
Setting up gdb (8.1-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Now `lldb` cannot load the core file anymore:

```
~$ lldb /usr/bin/node -c core
(lldb) target create "/usr/bin/node" --core "core"
error: core failed to load objfile for /home/ubuntu/core
error: Unable to find process plug-in for core file '/home/ubuntu/core'
```

How do I fix this? I like `lldb` better for what I am doing right now and want it back. I tried purging `gdb` and its additional packages, and then purging and re-installing `lldb`, but that did not fix anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `lldb` is terrible at diagnosing and reporting problems with itself. The `Unable to find process plug-in` error was a direct consequence of the `failed to load objfile` error.

The `failed to load objfile` can be caused by anything. In some versions it can be caused by permissions making the core file unreadable. In my case of *post hoc, ergo propter hoc*, the `gdb` installation was a red herring. The actual cause of the problem was that other processes consumed enough memory that there was not enough free memory to load the core image. Freeing up memory on the machine by stopping the memory hog processes fixed the problem.